# where on server is upload file stored

Tags: html, xampp

I'm attempting to upload a file to XAMPP for the Mac with the help of the following two files, html and php, respectively

upload.html:

```
<pre>
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

upload_file.php:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
?>
```

...and the server answers with:

```
Upload: noname.gif
Type: image/gif
Size: 2.31640625 kB
Stored in: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpjYIggr
```

I presume the upload succeeded since I got the above output. However when I look in the stored location for `phpjYIggr` in the shell, the file is not there.

Has the file been removed?

Answer (score 3):

That is a temporary file. When the script closes, the temporary file is removed. You need to move the file to a new directory where you want to keep it.

See [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)